# How can I prevents banners injected from WiFi access points?

Tags: javascript, security

There's a WiFi access point I connect to during my commute that injects ads onto pages. Is anyone familiar with this? How can I block this sort of thing from the sites I build?

The "how do I prevent JavaScript injections" articles and posts I see are usually for input fields.

Answer (score 3):

Use [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (i.e. `https://`) to serve your pages.  Networks can't tamper with traffic that's encrypted and signed.

If you want to ensure that users always access your site with TLS, don't serve pages over HTTP at all; instead, have HTTP requests just respond with a redirect to the equivalent HTTPS URL.  To provide additional security, use [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) to tell your users' browsers that they should always use access your site via HTTPS in the future.

Comment: I was just reading this article http://www.macworld.com/article/2976534/privacy/stop-ad-injections-with-https-connections-or-a-vpn.html

Comment: Thank you. I understand using ads to generate income, but putting ads on someone else's page just feels wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to prevent the injections, but you could crawl your html with javascript or use css rules to look for any unwelcome elements and remove them. If the ads are injected with a standard wrapper, you could use that.

```
$(".wifi-ad").remove()

.wifi-ad { display: none !important }
```

Or, you could do something like adding a class to all of your elements to identify them as your own code.

```
$(":not(.myClass)").remove()

*:not(.myClass) { display: none !imporant }
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to start a game of whack-a-mole with the ISP within the visitor's browser. This is really something that either the user and the ISP need to figure out, or ISPs in general need to be prevented from doing.

Comment: I agree. But if the extent of your reach is the front end of a website, something like this is all you can do. I wouldn't suggest this as a general plan, but only as a patch for a very specific use case.

Comment: this sounds like magic to me,, is there any ISP that injects ads on the pages?? how do thay do that from tech standpoint,, sounds crazy

Comment: @Kresimir Oooh, you soo naïve… ;-) HTML pages go through plain HTTP requests through the ISP's servers. Adding a little bit of Javascript or HTML after the `<body>` or so on the fly is trivial. Quite a few ISPs do so.

Comment: for god sake,, where does this world go to man... going offline now,, thans @deceze :)

Comment: @KresimirPendic You make the request through the ISP. If it's not encrypted it's plaintext. You can do anything you want with plaintext.

Comment: This is the reason google is pushing for HTTPS only connections